# Configuracoes ambiente timezones django postgres linux

Tags: python, postgresql, django, datetime, timezone

Bom dia a todos.

Tenho um site (Django) em um serviço de hospedagem linux com banco Postgre SQL que fica em Nova Jersey (EUA).
Os usuários estão no Brasil, portanto tenho uma diferença de timezone.

Tenho certeza que isso é algo bem bobo, com um ajuste resolvo tudo, mas estou confuso porque as mudanças e testes que fiz deram resultados incorretos.

Primeiro vou postar as configurações dos ambientes.

Servidor Linux (USA):

```
$cat /etc/timezone
Etc/UTC
```

Postgres Console (USA):

```
postgres=# show timezone;
UTC
```

Django settings.py (USA):

```
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Sao_Paulo'
USE_TZ = True
```

Mas agora vamos aos resultados.

Aqui no Brasil são:

> 10:07h

Lá no servidor Linux(USA):

> 12:07:52 UTC

Aqui pra mim já tá errado, lá não são 3 horas e diferença, 2 horas com horário de verão?

No POSTGRES:

```
select now();
2018-01-16 12:07:36.967415+00
```

Tenho um Modelo chamado COLETA que tem um campo que é chama-se DATA_LEITURA.

```
data_leitura = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

Então acabei de inserir um registro nessa tabela com o horário 10:07:16h.
Eu crio o datetime que atribuo ao modelo COLETA.data_leitura é esse:

```
br_tz = timezone('America/Sao_Paulo')
coleta.data_leitura = datetime(2018, 01, 16, 10, 07, 16, tzinfo=br_tz)
```

Acessei o console do linux (NJ) no postgres e dei um select:

```
SELECT data_leitura FROM coleta;
2018-01-16 15:13:16+00
```

O Valor exibido na página web para o cliente aqui no Brasil é:

> 15:13:16

Antes não tinha a linha br_tz = timezone('America/Sao_Paulo')
Então aparecia uma mensagem de NAIVE DATETIME e o horário também estava errado!

Estou experimentando mudar cada configuração e sempre dá mais errado ainda, isso quer dizer que há 2 fatores errados aí para se corrigir.
É minha primeira experiência nisso com estes ambientes e frameworks.

O que devo mudar? sugestões?
Obrigado desde já pela ajuda da comunidade!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode configurar uma variável de ambiente chamada [`TIMEZONE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES), que informa ao banco de dados a região na qual o cliente conectado ao servidor, isso faz com que o servidor saiba converter as horas de forma adequada:

```
SET TIMEZONE = 'America/Sao_Paulo';
SELECT NOW();
```

Comment: Mudei no /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf o valor para timezone="America/Sao_Paulo", e o horário apareceu mais errado ainda, agora que são 12:23 lá no banco está sendo gravado e exibido como 17:23h (5 horas diferença), isso quer dizer que essa configuração possa estar correta, mas algum outra está prejudicando o valor dessa.
Tentei mudar pra New_York também para ver como funciona e deixar UTC. Todas retornam valores errados!

Comment: Vc está mudando a configuração de timezone do servidor. Você precisa alterar a configuração do seu cliente.

Comment: O cliente abre uma página django(html) que mostra os dados trazidos direto do Coleta.filter(), não faço nenhum comando sobre essa mudança. Eu simplesmente lá no template/html coloquei {{coleta.data_leitura}}, como eu faria essa configuração? Pensei que o TIME_ZONE do django já faria isso sozinho, sempre que ele exibir, será o horário do BR. Até porque não terei usuários lá nos EUA, apenas o server está lá.

Comment: Pelo que percebi o problema está na INSERÇÃO dos dados, pois o SELECT que dou no postgres já mostra que o insert gravou a data já errada (converteu sozinho).

Comment: Se por acaso o dado *já foi inserido no banco de dados* usando o timezone incorreto, mudar as configurações do cliente e/ou servidor vai piorar o problema. Antes de mais nada, você deve corrigir os dados que foram gravados com o timezone incorreto.